# Why is the Number of numbers k with 1 < k < n which are relatively prime to n always odd if n>2?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, integers

I know this is probably a basic question to a mathematician, but why are the values in https://oeis.org/A109606 always odd, for n>2 ?

Answer (score 5):

If $\text{gcd}(k,n)=1$ then $\text{gcd}(n-k,n)=1$. The proof is very elementary, but if you struggle with it, I can always add it to this answer.

Now try to use this to finish your argument.

Comment: Also worth noting $\gcd(2n,n)=n$

Comment: So far this is what I have got. Assume gcd(n-k,n)>1.  This means we can write (n-k)=da and n=db, where d, a and b are integers and d>1.  Thus k=d(a-b) and we already know that n=db.  So d is a common divisor of k and n and therefore gcd(k,n)>1.

Comment: That should work fine

Answer (score 2):

That it because this number is one less than the number of $k$ such that $1\le k<n$, and the latter is $\varphi(n)$, which is even if $n>2$.

Indeed let $\displaystyle\prod_i p_i^{r_i}$ be the prime factorisation of $n$. Then
$$\varphi(n)=\prod_i p_i^{r_i-1}(p_i-1)$$
If $n$ has an odd prime factor $p_i$, $\varphi(n)$ is a multiple of $p_i-1$, which is even.

Otherwise $n=2^r$. As $n>2$, $r\ge 2$, so $\,\varphi(n)$ is a multiple of $2^{r-1}\ge 2$.